# In a regular table, is there a way to put an outer border on a table and leave out the table header?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, and at the top of the table is the table header with some text. I want to be able to only put a border on the table body, and leave the table header untouched, but I don't know how.

I have only tried applying a border to the default class for table body.

```css
<table class="float-left">
 <thead>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th>
    This is some text I want outside of the border
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    This is some cell data I want inside the border
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

All I need is for the tbody to be the only bordered thing in the table, and when I try and give it a border, nothing happens.

Comment: _"I have only tried applying a border to the default class for table body."_ And what happened when you did that? Post your CSS as well please

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get this!

First and most straight: add `border-collapse` to table

```
table { border-collapse: collapse }
tbody { border: dashed }
```

2) use `outline` rather than border

```
tbody { outline: dashed }
```

(positive or negative `outline-offset:` can be used for adjustment)

3) use `box-shadow` rather than border

```
tbody { box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
tbody, tbody th, tbody td, tbody tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="float-left">
 <thead>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th>header</th>
   <th>header</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>content</td>
   <td>content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>content</td>
   <td>content</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This creates a border for `tbody` as well as all `th`, `tr` and `td` elements inside the tbody.